# Unable to launch Selenium with Python in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, selenium

I'm getting **Unresolved import: webdriver
 Found at: selenium.webdriver.__init__
2.44.0** issue when i'm trying to launch selenium with **python** in **Eclipse**

My sample code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
driver.close()
```

Using **Python 2.7** , **Pydev 2.2**

**Installed Selenium through PIP**

```
pip install selenium
Downloading/unpacking selenium
Running setup.py (path:c:\users\ajay_t~1\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_ajay_talpur\selenium\setup.py) egg_info for package selenium
Installing collected packages: selenium
Running setup.py install for selenium
Successfully installed selenium
```

**When updating Packages**

```
pip install -U selenium
Requirement already up-to-date: selenium in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
```

What else i missed please tell me so that i can start executions.

Comment: kindly refer : https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/py

Comment: Hi thanks for providing above link but i think i had followed the steps which it says.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SeleniumWebdriver+Python+Eclipse Pre-Requisites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637352/seleniumwebdriverpythoneclipse-pre-requisites)

Comment: Thanks for quoting "possible duplicate", i didn't find any answer there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update Environment variable by adding Python Directory path & site packages path.And retry : C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages;

Comment: i've added the C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages; in system env variables but still getting error.

Comment: Does this import works directly through command prompt? With below set of steps: Start CMD -> Type "Python" > Once interactive python console starts check if "from selenium import webdriver" import statement works without any failure

Comment: And please make sure you are using Eclipse Version (3.8/4.3 onwards) as per http://pydev.org/download.html with all the requirements fulfilled

Comment: Hi it is working now,i tried import selenium print selenium.__file__ then it pointed to some .pyc file which is a faulty one, thanks it is resolved now.

Comment: Hi can you please look into this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719471/unable-to-launch-selenium-with-python-in-mac